# Changing a javascript variable inside a DIV using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

Firstly - i'm not even sure if the syntax is correct, but what i'm trying to do is, i have a div showing an animated image sequence which picks a position using a variable.

I will eventually use JSON to feed the value being changed, but for now i'm just trying to understand how to use JQuery to change the variable. Here's the code:

```
<div id="noiseAnimDiv" style="float: center; background-color: #ffffff; ">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./animatedpng.js">
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var stoptheClock = 3;
    noiseAnim = new AnimatedPNG('noise', './noise/noise0.png', 8, 50);
    noiseAnim.draw(false);
    noiseAnim.setFrameDelay(stoptheClock, 1000); //spin yet stay on value 3
 </script>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(
function() {
    $("#stoptheClock").val(6); //
 }
);
</script>
```

Any help much appreciated

code is live btw at so you can at least see the animation seq
http://ashleyjamesbrown.com/fgbp/noise.htm

Comment: Where is the "stoptheClock" element? I don't see it anywhere?

Comment: @Antiga stopTheClock is a var `var stoptheClock = 3;`

Comment: Right.. which has nothing to do with the jQuery selector $("#stoptheClock"). That is a selector that looking for an HTML element with an ID of "stoptheClock". There isn't one that I can see. It has nothing to do with that variable.

Comment: @Antiga my bad, looks like that's the main problem.. let me check

Answer (score 1):

The `AnimatedPNG` library you are using only checks the variable's value once - when initialized. in your code, you are changing the value after initializing it.

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
    $("#stoptheClock").val(6); //
}
);
```

Should be

```
function() {
    stoptheClock = 6; 
    noiseAnim.draw(false);
    noiseAnim.setFrameDelay(stoptheClock,1000);
}
```

You are ***not*** using JQuery for any useful cause in your code, therefore I have removed all of the Jquery parts.

Comment: thanks a lot for this. i assumed i needed to point to the div element first. i have tried this code however it doesn't change the value held in stoptheclock (which changes which image the spinning dial stops on so i can tell because it is still stopping on 3) Is it because its redcelared inside the div as var stoptheCLock = 3; which over writes the jquery change ?

Comment: @AshleyJamesBrown have you updated your code at: http://ashleyjamesbrown.com/fgbp/noise.htm to reflect this change?

Comment: @AshleyJamesBrown have a look at the new code, it works on my pc

Comment: ok sure, i see the update. i thought it might be the declaration. it doesn't work on my browser unless i wrap it back inside the $ document ready jquery. Ill need the function to be able to read in teh value of stop the clock from a JSON file which will be read every minute. Ill need JQuery for that wont i ?

Comment: @AshleyJamesBrown you don't _need_ JQuery for anything, It just makes things a bit easier **BUT** if you only use it 5 times or something, loading 84KB to save a few seconds and bytes is unnecessary. BTW: is your animation thing working now?

Comment: yes its working but i had to put the document ready wrap back in around your suggested code to make it run or else it flagged an error in chrome and didnt run. The function will eventually need to have data passed in to it from a JSON so ill review my syntax but its possible ill be back ;-) for help. Thanks for your syntax/help/guidance - im not really used to javascript - im more of a java/processing kinda guy

Comment: the function does need to have stoptheclock read into it though and then declare rather than inside the function. this way when i read the json i can pass the read value into the function to determine the value to stop on.

Comment: the error was the first open bracket. ill take ascreenshot